# Getting javax.script.ScriptException: com.mongodb.MongoException: not authorized for query on default.paymentHeader

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter

I am using Groovy to query on MongoDB and I am getting not authorized in querying in MongoDB. Can you please check if there is a problem on my script?

DBName          default 
Collection  paymentHeader

```
import com.mongodb.*;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.config.MongoDBHolder;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject; 
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;

//Get DB
DB db = MongoDBHolder.getDBFromSource("SITDB","${DBName}","${username}","${password}");
boolean auth = db.authenticate("${username}","${password}".toCharArray());

//Get Collection
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("${Collection}");

//Find ApplicationNum
//collection.find({applicationNum: "${applicationId}"});
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("applicationNum", "${applicationId}");
DBObject result = collection.findOne(query);
SampleResult.setResponseData(result.toString().getBytes());
```

Response code: 500
Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: com.mongodb.MongoException: not authorized for query on default.paymentHeader

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have anything with JMeter, you need to provide [read permissions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#read) for the `${username}` onto `default.paymentHeader` collection.

Also be aware that you should not reference [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) as `${username}`, you should use [`vars` shorthand](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instead like `vars.get('username')`

More information: [JSR223 Sampler Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), in particular:

> JMeter processes function and variable references before passing the script field to the interpreter, so the references will only be resolved once. Variable and function references in script files will be passed verbatim to the interpreter, which is likely to cause a syntax error. In order to use runtime variables, please use the appropriate props methods, e.g.
>
> ```
> props.get("START.HMS");
>
> props.put("PROP1","1234");
> ```